# Group instance not showing correctly

Tags: groups

When I create a group instance a plain-axis shape is displayed instead of an actual mesh.

It happens only in one of my scenes, when I create a new scene from scratch groups are working fine. I guess I must have messed up one of the settings?

[image]

Comment: Press Shift + H with the instance selected to hide all other objects. Then Shift + C to view all. Is the group truly empty? If nothing shows, check the active layers of the group in the properties panel.

Comment: Thanks Leander, your suggestion helped me to figure out what's wrong. Group object was instantiating correctly and is visible but it's location is very very far away from parent so i wasn't able to see the actual mesh in a viewport, only representation of it's origin i guess (cross-shaped gizmo). Now i just need to figure out why group instance is beign located so weird. Thanks!

Comment: The groups origin is always at (0, 0, 0). If some meshes are at (100, 0, 0) and you instanciate the group at (99, 0, 0), the instanced meshes won't be next to it, but rather at (199, 0, 0). Always position the meshes at the scene origin if you want to use group instances.